# NodeJs unit test actual results not correct

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, npm

I'm making a unittest with simple methods and if statements but my expected results must be 8 but the test gives a error that it is actually 7

Here is my unit test:

```
describe("Discount code 10% + 20% age", function() {
        it("If code is abcd or efgh give 10% discount and if age is lower than 15 or higher than 65 plus 20% discount ", function() {
          // Hier worden variabelen gekopeld aan de returns van de functies
          var testCaseDiscount1 = converter.calculateTotalPrice(66, "abcd");
          var testCaseDiscount2 = converter.calculateTotalPrice(15, "efgh");
          var testCaseDiscount3 = converter.calculateTotalPrice(64, "fffhfh");
          var testCaseDiscount4 = converter.calculateTotalPrice(20, "fdhdfhfd");
          var testCaseDiscount5 = converter.calculateTotalPrice(15, "notgoodcode");
          var testCaseDiscount6 = converter.calculateTotalPrice(67, "notgoodcode");

          // Hier worden de antwoorden vergeleken.
          expect(testCaseDiscount1).to.equal(7);
          expect(testCaseDiscount2).to.equal(7);
          expect(testCaseDiscount3).to.equal(10);
          expect(testCaseDiscount4).to.equal(10);
          expect(testCaseDiscount5).to.equal(8);
          expect(testCaseDiscount6).to.equal(8);
        });
      });
```

My if statement:

```
exports.calculateTotalPrice = function(age, code) {
    var price = 10;
if (age >= 65 || age <= 15 && code == "abcd" || code == "efgh") {
    var result = (price / 100 * 30 );
    var price = (price - result);
    return price; 

    }  else if (age >= 65 || age <= 15 && code == "notgoodcode") {
    var result = (price / 100 * 20 );
    var price = (price - result);
    return price; 

    } else {
        return price;
    }   
}
```

and my result will be:

```
 AssertionError: expected 7 to equal 8
      + expected - actual

      -7
      +8

      at Context.<anonymous> (test\TicketTest.js:50:38)
```

I think this is weird because the age 15 with "notgoodcode" will pass but the age above 65 will never pass and will redirect to the first if statement not the second one.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to operator precedence. `&&` is executed before `||`. To get the expected result, you need to add parentheses.

```
if ((age >= 65 || age <= 15) && code == "abcd" || code == "efgh") {

}  else if ((age >= 65 || age <= 15)  && code == "notgoodcode") {
```